# How to implement *args and **kwargs in argparse python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is my code

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("required_arg", metavar="username:pass@hostname")
parser.add_argument("--optional_arg", 
                    help="This optional argument should have args and 
                          kwargs implemented in it as I want to make 
                          it flexible eg.
                          it may have optional_arg1, 
                          optional_arg2, key1=value1, key2=value2 or 
                          it may have optional_arg1, key1=value1, 
                          key2=value2, key3=value3")
```

Can please anyone show me the way to implement *args and **kwargs in this add_argument() section?

Comment: Having some trouble with formatting, so i will just say try adding `parser.parse_args()` at the end. It handles *args **kwargs for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to look at doing something like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='subparser')
```